# How to delete a contributor on GitHub repository page?

Tags: git, github

I have multiple GitHub accounts, say `A` and `B`, and I'm in a project at the remote repository of `A`.
Yesterday, I was surprised to find that there was somehow the account name of `B` on the `Contributors` list at the repository page of `A`.

I checked the commit log and I found that there was somehow the name of `B` signed for some of the commits. So I used `git filter-repo` command to forcibly rewrite the Author name and Committer name and email address from those of `B` to those of `A`.

Then, I forcibly pushed it with `git push -f origin` and I confirmed that the commit log of a remote repository of `A` was completely rewritten as I expected.

However, there still remains `B`'s name in the `Contributors` list at the repository of `A`.

Anyway, I want to delete `B`'s name from `Contributors` list at `A`'s repository page, because I don't want to let anybody know that the owner of `A` account is identical to that of `B` account.

I would appreciate if you give me some advice.

Comment: This is just my own small project so rewriting the commit log, I think, is not a big deal this time.

Comment: Check not only the author but also the committer with `git log --format=full`. If there's still no issue, maybe consider removing/recreating the project?

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the remote rep and pushed the local one again.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this, GitHub appears to treat the list of "Contributors" as append-only: whenever it sees a new one, it adds it to the list, but it never removes from that list. See [this repo](https://github.com/Smittyvb/wrong-contribs) which lists someone who never committed in the Contributors list, despite only having one commit (that they didn't author). I did this by pushing a commit as myself, then pushing one as torvalds, then force-pushing back to my commit. Despite this, GitHub still shows torvalds as a contributor.

Go to the full "Contributors" graph in the insights tab, and check if `B` listed there. The data for this graph is always calculated using the actual commit graph. If `B` is listed there, then GitHub still thinks `B` *did* make some commits. In that case, you should double-check that you fixed all commits belonging to `B`. Click on "N commits" to see what commits GitHub thinks `B` did:
[image: Arrow pointing to "1 commit" on top of a graph]

If no commits are attributed to `B`, [contact GitHub support](https://support.github.com/request) (I think *Remove data from a repository I own or control* would be the right topic to select) and ask them to re-generate the Contributors list.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this issue. If there is no functionality to remove a contributor which was once appended on the list, it seems it cannot be helped. I'm thinking about making a request to GItHub support for adding new functionality to remove contributor from the list. For this time, I solved this by deleting the remote repository and pushing my local one to it. Thank you.